# All contacts have disappeared from iPhone

Tags: ios, icloud, contacts

All contacts have vanished from my iPhone4. Group contacts are all that are visible, and they are Facebook contacts.

I have tried uploading SIM contacts to phone. I have turned off the phone and back on. I have synced to my PC and no contacts visible. I have tried to connect to iCloud and error message reads cannot connect to server. Phone reflects iCloud backup not on. I do not know what else to do.

Comment: Where do you feel the contacts are stored? Are some only on the device or are all of them in cloud backed storage like iCloud, Google or Exchange? iOS can read contacts from the SIM card, but never writes them back or uses that for long term storage of contacts.

Comment: well talked with ATT he suggested i again go into icloud.com attempt to accept conditions and terms and all contacts will populate....did not happen!  i see all my contacts on icloud after signing in but error message "cannot connect to server".  as i scrolled to bottom of terms did not see option to accept..!!?? thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would start from a computer and log into iCloud.com and inspect that your account is in good order and add a contact / review what contacts are already stored in the cloud.

At that point, you can troubleshoot the iOS to iCloud sync in knowing that it isn't a problem with your account itself or a server side error.